# Observable stream from StackExchange Redis Pub Sub subscription

Tags: c#, system.reactive, stackexchange.redis

**OBJECTIVE:**

I am using StackExchange Redis Client. My objective is to create an Observable stream from the Pub Sub Subscriber exposed by the Client, that can then in turn support *1-n* subscriptions by Observables, that each have their own filter via LINQ. (Publishing is working as planned, the issue is purely around Subscription to the Event Stream on a specific channel.)

**BACKGROUND:**

I am using Redis Pub Sub as part of an Event Sourced CQRS application. The specific use case is to publish Events to multiple subscribers that then update the various Read Models, send emails etc.

Each of these Subscribers need to filter the Event Types that they handle, and for this I am looking to use Rx .Net (Reactive Extensions), with LINQ, to
provide a filter criteria on the Event Stream, to efficiently handle reacting only to Events of interest. Using this approach removes the need for registering Handlers with an event bus implementation, and allows me to add new projections to the system by deploying *1-n* Microservices that each have *1-n* Observables subscribed to the Event Stream with their own specific filters.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED:**

1) I have created a class inheriting from ObservableBase, overriding the SubscribeCore method, which receives subscription requests from Observables, stores them in a ConcurrentDictionary, and as each Redis notification arrives from the channel, loops through the registered Observable subscribers and calls their OnNext method passing the RedisValue.

2) I have created a Subject, that also accepts subscriptions from Observables, and calls their OnNext method. Again, the use of Subjects appears to be frowned upon by many.

**THE ISSUE:**

The approaches I have tried do function (at least superficially), with varying levels of performance, but `feel like a hack`, and that I am not using Rx in the way it was intended.

I see many comments that the built-in Observable methods should be used where at all possible, for example Observable.FromEvent, but that seems to be impossible to do with the StackExchange Redis Clients Subscription API, at least to my eyes.

I also understand that the preferred method for receiving a stream and forwarding to *multiple* Observers is to use a **ConnectableObservable**, which would seem to be designed for the very scenario I face (Each Microservice will internally have *1-n* Observables subscribed). At the moment, I cannot get my head around how to connect a **ConnectableObservable** to the notifications from StackExchange Redis, or if it offers real benefit over an **Observable**.

**UPDATE**:

Although completion is not an issue in my scenario (Disposal is fine), error handling *is* important; e.g. isolating errors detected in one subscriber to prevent all subscriptions terminating.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is an extension method you can use to create an `IObservable<RedisValue>` from an `ISubscriber` and a `RedisChannel`:

```
public static IObservable<RedisValue> WhenMessageReceived(this ISubscriber subscriber, RedisChannel channel)
{
    return Observable.Create<RedisValue>(async (obs, ct) =>
    {
        // as the SubscribeAsync callback can be invoked concurrently
        // a thread-safe wrapper for OnNext is needed
        var syncObs = Observer.Synchronize(obs);
        await subscriber.SubscribeAsync(channel, (_, message) =>
        {
            syncObs.OnNext(message);
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return Disposable.Create(() => subscriber.Unsubscribe(channel));
    });
}
```

As there is no completion of Redis channels the resulting `IObservable` will never complete, however you may drop the `IDisposable` subscription to unsubscribe from the Redis channel (this will be done automatically by many Rx operators).

Usage could be like so:

```
var subscriber = connectionMultiplexer.GetSubscriber();

var gotMessage = await subscriber.WhenMessageReceived("my_channel")
    .AnyAsync(msg => msg == "expected_message")
    .ToTask()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Or as per your example:

```
var subscriber = connectionMultiplexer.GetSubscriber();

var sendEmailEvents = subscriber.WhenMessageReceived("my_channel")
    .Select(msg => ParseEventFromMessage(msg))
    .Where(evt => evt.Type == EventType.SendEmails);

await sendEmailEvents.ForEachAsync(evt => 
{
    SendEmails(evt);
}).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Other microservices may filter differently.

Comment: Neat, I like the approach, +1. (Before accepting answers I prefer to wait a couple to days to allow others an opportunity.) Do you see any advantage in using a ConnectableObservable over an Observable, as mentioned in my question; most sources describe the ConnectableObservable as being designed for a scenario where a stream is read, and then published to multiple secondary Observers. Although completion is not an issue in my scenario (Disposal is fine), error handling is important; isolating them to prevent all subscriptions terminating.

Comment: If you want to share the same subscription with multiple observers then you will need to use an `IConnectableObservable`, that can be done by using `.Publish()` or invoking an of the other `.Multicast()` implementations on the result of `WhenMessageReceived`. It shouldn't change how `WhenMessageReceived` is implemented at all.

Comment: Yes, tested, and excellent performance with `WhenMessageReceived` returning a `IConnectableObservable`, and 10 concurrent subscriptions to that `IConnectableObservable`. Good solution.

Comment: hey, on the face of it, this is exactly what I need as well, but I am using .NET Core (with System.Reactive.Core 3.1.1) and I am struggling to find the .AnyAsync() and .ToTask() extensions to make the above example work for me. Are these also required to be implemented alongside the .WhenMessageReceived()? or perhaps have these not reached the .NET Core implementation yet?

Comment: @Alastair `System.Reactive.Core` does not mean it is the one you require when using .NET Core, just that it is the core functionality of Rx (base classes etc). 

`AnyAsync` and `ToTask` are part of the [`System.Reactive.Linq`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive.Linq/) package, you may either add a dependency to that package directly or just use [`System.Reactive`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive/) which will pull in many supported Rx packages automatically. Both of these packages support .NET Core.

Comment: @Alastair I personally just add `System.Reactive` as a dependency (the exception is when I am working on a library I plan to publish, in which case I take the smallest subset of dependencies).

Comment: Although this answer was very helpful, it's missing one important bit of information: Rx operators are very often not thread safe (GroupBy for example, but there's more). Since Redis notifications may come in concurrently, it's good to add a `.Synchronize()` call after the `SubscribeAsync()` call. Your performance will get a penalty, but I couldn't find any other way of making this stuff work without weird, intermittent exceptions.

Comment: @MarekM. Thanks for your feedback, I will edit the answer to add a synchronized wrapper around `obs`.